# How to monitor the change in an element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, monitor

I want to make a monitor that checks for the change in text of specific element and then sends me a notification through discord, im not sure how exactly I would do this. I know how to check what is currently in the element but I dont know how to compare that to a new change and give me an update. Does anyone know how I could do this?
This the current code I have written for finding the text of the element and storing it in a variable but im not sure what to do next

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=r"ChromePath, options=option)
 driver.get("Mywebsite")
 sleep(3)
 link = driver.find_element("xpath", 'xpath goes here')
 link.click()
 sleep(2)
 text = driver.find_element("id", 'name')
 text.send_keys("what im searching for")
 sleep(2)
 button = driver.find_element('id', "name")
 button.click()
 sleep(2)
 element = driver.find_element("xpath", 'xpath goes here')
 currentText = element.text #current text of element
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a while loop that will check this element again and again until it is changed

```
currentText = element.text #current text of element
updatedText = element.text
while currentText == updatedText:
    updatedText = driver.find_element("xpath", 'xpath goes here').text
    # You can put here any sleep to repeat this check once in some time. For example once in 10 seconds
    sleep(10)
# Now you can do anything with the new text, for example print it
print(updatedText)
```